# Receive Port does not appear to be polling

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a One-Way Receive port with a WCF-Custom XMLReceive location that is using a sqlBinding type. The Receive location binding is set to poll every minute and execute a SQL Server Stored Procedure. There is a procedure in the "polledDataAvailableStatement" and a "PollingStatement." The problem is, these never get executed and there are no errors generated which I can find.

I have multiple ports/locations setup like this, and they all work correctly except for one. This one works correctly on my own machine, but when I deploy to production it does not. SQL Profiler is telling me the stored procedure never fires. I am using the default settings for everything in the binding except for the names of the procedures and polling times. There is no error logged in biztalk. Tracked message events shows other orchestrations, but not the one mapped to the port in question.

I've tried re-exporting and importing the MSI. I've set the service account to sysadmin on the database server. I've validated the connection strings by copying/pasting them from another receive location which is working. I've restarted the hosted instance and of course the application. Nothing I do seems to get that location to fire. Looking for trouble-shooting tips.

Comment: The host instance you restarted is indeed the host instance the receive location is configured to use? The receive location is running, doesn't shut down on its own, and nothing is appearing in either the event log (of the server the host instance is on) or in SQL Server?

Comment: All correct... we are also looking at the number of active ports in performance monitor. There are 2 (should be 3). ie. it's saying the port isn't active?


Late yesterday evening thru a series of many restarts/redeploys/recreates this issue magically went away. The only thing we actually changed: We pointed to the port binding directly to a SQL box instead of the friendly DNS. note: other ports are still pointed to the DNS and working correctly. Very odd. I'm afraid to change this back again / play with it. lol

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before, which reflected an issue with the communication of DTC between this specific SQL server and BTS.

You could try to troubleshoot this issue when you set the "UseAmbientTransaction" property to false.
This avoids you're having issues regarding the distributed transaction coordinator between the two servers.
Note that whenever this property is set to False, the PollDataAvailableStatement is not executed.

Restart your hosts afterwards.

**Influence of UseAmbientTransaction:** http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3470.typed-polling-with-wcf-sql-adapter-best-practices-and-troubleshooting-tips.aspx

**Configure DTC:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248704.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird that this is happening, especially that you are not seeing any error in (EventViewer Logs of server where receive host is running). It can happen only in following conditions:

- You have a Service Window on Receive Port, i.e. it will be active during certain time of the day.
- Your receive host instance is throttling, still in this case some calls should reach SQL server
- Your receive port is connection a different database server by mistake

If all is setup as expected, then try creating a new Receive port and use a simple select statement to test it out.

Comment: I don't think the receive port is running / active. If we add the count of active receive locations in Perf Mon, it shows 2 (there should be 3).

However, this was the most helpful answer as we did try the last thing: Create a new test port. We couldn't get it to work (even though we were copying the connection string from working ports). So, we changed the string a little and pointed it directly to the SQL Box (was using a friendly DNS), all of sudden it all worked. Note: This is nothing more than a DNS name, not a vip. Still don't understand why this is working on some ports and not others.

Comment: Check the DNS on server where your receive host is running and if it is responding using ping. do you have other ports running on same server as this one

Comment: Yes... 2 others on the same server. I can get a response using PING which comes back as our fqdn of the sql box.

Those 2 others are using the same friendly DNS and it works. Freaky!

Comment: Can you try setting up WCF-SQL adapter and use configure option to create yr connection string with FQDN

Comment: Do you have more than one receive location listening on the same SQL server with the same SQL request ? how many BizTalk servers do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your host instance account has permission to run that stored procedure?

Comment: this is a question rather than an answer - I realize you don't have enough rep to post a comment, but perhaps you could rephrase this as an answer anyway - for example, "This could be caused by account permissions" with an explanation of why and how to fix it.